# How to return text when there is no data?

Tags: java, android, android-view, achartengine

I am using achartengine to draw a pie chart. It's working fine if I receive data. But when there is no data it crashes.

My class structure is like this

```
Class Piegraph{
  public GraphicalView getView(Context context, JSONObject json) {
  // getting data in json variable



   return ChartFactory.getPieChartView(context, series, renderer);
  }
}
```

The above structure works fine unless there is no data to parse.

Instead of crashing, I want to return some text and show in the layout.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried throwing an Exception?

Comment: yes..i finally i need to return graphicalview from this function
so that i can get a view
GraphicalView gView = pie.getView(context,MainActivity.json);
in my main activity

Comment: If you please guide me with some example

Comment: Is `ChartFactory.getPieChartView(context, series, renderer);` throwing an exception then?

Comment: function should return something . I am not getting how to write exception for this function

Comment: What's the exception that is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are creating a series object even if it is empty.  That way you will be able to pass back an empty series and still get a graph, albeit a blank one.

If that isn't the problem, you can try

```
Class Piegraph{
  public GraphicalView getView(Context context, JSONObject json) {
  // getting data in json variable

  //check series has items to fill Chart
  if(series.getItemCount()>0){
     return ChartFactory.getPieChartView(context, series, renderer);
  }else{

     return //a specific graph with specific content that specifies 
            //"there is no data to return from your json object"

  }
}
```

Comment: its good suggestion, but how do i draw a graph with specific content that represents no data... specially pie chart

Comment: I would recommend adding a category such as "no data" to an empty series and setting its value to either 0% of the piechart or 100% of the piechart.  That way, the whole piechart will represent the "no data" category.